# How to convert json to form in Django?

Tags: django

I'm developing a Django project, and the team want to seperate the front-end and the back-ed, so I'm using Django to develop api. The format of the data transmitting is json. However, I want to use the defalt user package (django.contrib.auth), and I have to use Form. How could I convert the json received from the frontend to the form that I'm going to use in backend? thanks!

I have tried the silly code as below and it does not work.

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def register(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
    response = {"status": "success"}
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        print("valid")
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how your view must look if you want to register new user with custom form :**

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        response = {}
        
        if form.is_valid():
            # The form is valid, now we can save the user in the db
            new_user = form.save()
            response = {"status": "success", "message": "User created"}
            return JsonResponse(response)
        else:
            # Invalid form
            response = {"status": "error", "message": "Form is invalid"}
    else:
        # It's not a post request ( GET or others)
        # Instantiate an empty form
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()

        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'register_template.html', context=context)
```